# Proverb having the use of past tense

Tags: sentence-meaning, past-tense, present-tense, proverbs, structure

**Nothing comes out of the sack but what was in it.**

It is a proverb. As it is taught, a proverb is always constructed by using simple present tense, here this one has past form in its second clause. I googled it and found the same structure on every site. What is grammatical rule in this above mentioned structure.

Comment: I have found "Nothing comes out of a sack but what is put into it".

Comment: "As it is taught" - by who?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason that a proverb must use the present tense.

> For want of a nail the shoe was lost; for want of a shoe the horse was lost; and for want of a horse the man was lost.

> Rome wasn't built in a day.

> The course of true love never did run smooth.

A proverb is a short expression, giving some traditional wisdom or advice.  Most are phrased in the present tense, but that is just because they are usually about the present, or at least about some kind of general truth. General truths are expressed in present tense.

But a proverb is not limited grammatically. A proverb can have any combination of tenses that is possible in English.  In your example, it simply means that what was put into the sack (in the past) is the only thing that can come out of the sack (now)